# What is the name of two commutative squares?

Tags: terminology

How do you refer two commutative squares sharing one side as follows? [image: a diagram]

Comment: There is no name for this.

Comment: It's a map in the category $\mathcal C^{[3]}$ where $[3]$ is the category $0\to 1\to 2$. Yeah, useless. :)

Comment: I would refer to the commutative diagram above as "the commutative diagram above".

Comment: If you know about category theorem: If both squares are pushouts, then the outer "square" is a pushout, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are known as *commutative diagrams*. They come in various sizes, shapes et cetera.

Comment: I am not sure that the actual sizing of the diagram matters much;)

Comment: @Ma: As a foreigner I got the impression that you were looking for a proper English generic term here. If you knew this, and were looking for a term for a commutative diagram of this particular form, then I misunderstood, and apologize for the light-hearted tone of the answer. The crowd seems to agree that there is no term for this particular type of a commutative diagram.